# "They have *both* got ..." or "They *both* have got ..."

Tags: british-english, coordination, adjuncts

So I had to check my friend's homework, but I myself don't even know the answers. For instance:

> 1. "Yes, they are. They are both tall and *they have **both** got brown eyes.*
> 2. "Yes, they are. They are both tall and *they **both** have got brown eyes.*

I am leaning towards "they have both got" (#1), but I cannot rationalize why, or why the other option would be bad.

Which is correct, and why?

Edit: Her teacher wasn't exactly of much help when she said that *it is just the way it is*. The answers are shown below.

A copy of her homework is below:

[image: illustration of the book]

A copy of the answers (provided by her teacher):
[image: illustration of the answers]

Comment: Is there no example sentences or explanation in the text? Kind of weird to test over structures not previously explained and exemplified.

Comment: Sadly, there is not. The course is primarily oral and only the homework is in writing.

Comment: "They both have got" sounds grating to my AmE-ear. We'd say, "Both have brown eyes".

Comment: All the options seem correct to me (though I agree that not using "got" seems even better). What am I missing here? I can see how one word order changes the meaning for verbs such as "like", but not for "have" or "are".

Comment: Sadly, the best answer is going to be what that  teacher says it is. And, yes, the whole "have *got*" usage is *[mostly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english)* British English. But to me (AmE), both options are fine. That is also the case for #1 (although the option you chose sounds better to me).

Comment: That is a bad test.

Comment: *Have got* = *have* is a strictly colloquial idiom, and you're unlikely to hear either version you offer. The likeliest version is * ... they've both got ...*

Comment: @δοῦλος What! *Have got* = *have* is primarily a US idiom, although it has been making headway in the UK for a generation or two. What is distinctly British is use of *got* as the past participle of lexical *get*, where 'Standard' US English calls for *gotten*.

Comment: @StoneyB What! Did you even click on my link to read [another statement](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/120752/78616) that accords with mine?

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Let us know what your sister puts down, and if the teacher marks it wrong, then let us know and we'll most likely be able to prove that your sister's answer is "correct" (that is, is standard usage in today's English). A related topic is **quantificational adjuncts**, which is discussed in the 2002 *CGEL*, pages 102, 413, 428.

Comment: (cont.) In other words, the following seem to be fine: *"They are both tall"* and *"They both are tall"*; as are *"They have both got brown eyes"* and *"They both have got brown eyes"*.

Comment: @StoneyB The 2002 *CGEL*, page 112 [59], makes the comment that "have got" is *Characteristically BrE*; but I have marked in the margins that I disagree with them. For I am AmE and that usage "have got" was very common when I was growing up, and the teachers (prescriptively) kept trying to rid us of that usage. I guess they failed. Also, my community (in the USA) were not tea drinkers. I'm finding that I have a lot of disagreements with CGEL over their judgments of BrE vs AmE dialect usage.

Comment: Also, note that the book *Cambridge Grammar of English,* published 2006, and authored by Carter and McCarthy is not considered to be a reference grammar (imo), and it is full of errors. (Yes, I do have a hardcopy of it on my bookshelf, but I rarely open it up nowadays.)

Comment: Judging from the results I found on Google, I believe the book the OP's sister uses is *[Success Elementary Workbook](http://www.amazon.com/Success-Elementary-WB-CD-Pack/dp/0582855470)*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That is correct, but in an ideal world the language does not depend on the book!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Sure! But wouldn't it be better to know where it's from and who wrote it? At least, now I can say, reasonably confidently, that what publisher published the book. PS. That's why it's recommended to cite our sources. Not only because we want to avoid plagiarism, but it's helpful to review our and their judgements.

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I think the reason why you (and others here and results in corpora) *seem* to prefer *They are **both** tall and they have **both** got brown eyes* is probably because it's exactly the same position as the mid-position of many adverbs in English. (Compare: *He is **definitely** tall and he's **definitely** got brown eyes*.) Though *both* is not an adverb, it's probably easier for English speakers to handle these *both*'s this way.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, that is a reason why that version is often preferred ("both", which is a determinative, can be located after the auxiliary verb--CGEL page 102). Too bad you don't have a copy of the 2002 *CGEL*, or else you could be writing a definitive answer post! :D

Comment: At first I presumed you were asking about British English. But when I saw how you spelled "realize", I realized you were not. I tagged your question as British-English, as American responders are likely to tell you that "got" is superfluous in both examples.

Comment: The course is in British English indeed, so the tag is correct. If I used American English in my question I apologise for it, my browser's spell-checker autocorrects to AE.

Comment: @F.E and StoneyB the fact that *have got* (meaning possession) is more prominent in British English is well known. It is not limited to one book. It is firmly established. You can find many sources for this, if you want to search for "*have got* British English". Just because you two are unaware of this fact does not make it untrue.

Comment: @δοῦλος Do note that in a previous comment of mine, there is this: *"The 2002 CGEL, page 112 [59], makes the comment that "have got" is Characteristically BrE; but I have marked in the margins that I disagree with them."* That would seriously imply that I'm familiar with what you are calling a "fact". And I'm also aware of what that book *Cambridge Grammar of English* (published 2006, and authored by Carter and McCarthy) had opined on its page 883.

Comment: I've gotten the answers (according to her teacher), but they make little sense to me.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Hang in there! Someone will probably provide a solid answer, with vetted grammar sources and solid reasoning (maybe during the weekend?). I did a quick look at the teacher's answers. There are a number of grammar issues in play: such as, transitive verbs (e.g. "play") have a resistance to having some kinds of adjunct (e.g. "both") between the verb and its object. Also complicating the issue is that the word "both" can be a marker of coordination, e.g. "She plays both the guitar and piano".

Comment: @F.E Whoops. I didn't extrapolate your personal usage growing up to be indicative of a universal truth.

Comment: @δοῦλος I apologize for not responding to your comment; I've been looking for documented answers and it's turning out more complicated than I expected. I'll be working on it this weekend and will post as a new question.

Comment: I am interested, Stephan, if your friend's teacher is a native English speaker. The answer *it[/that] is just the way it is* is often used by native speakers. In fact, we could use it for every question asked here, ha hah.

Comment: I am not sure she is a native speaker, I will ask whenever I get the chance. My friend described her as Dolores Umbridge, so that might give you some insight O_o

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I've started an answer post, and have deleted it (so I can work on it in semi-privacy); though, you probably don't have the number of rep-points required to see that deleted answer post of mine. I'll try to finish it up by sometime tonight, if I'm lucky. I just wanted to let you know that, er, someone is working on a new answer. :)

Comment: That's great to hear :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are six (6) pairs of choices in her homework: that is, six (6) questions. So that gives a total of twelve (12) choices. Of those twelve (12) choices, all except for two (2) are grammatical.

It so happens that four questions have no wrong answer, and only two questions have a right/wrong pair as answers. (Aside: I like that kind of homework!)

---

**CAVEAT:** *Some of the grammar info that I'm presenting in this post might be intentionally--or unintentionally--over simplified. Hopefully there won't be any egregious errors. (I'm sure I'll get dinged if there are.)*

Let's first do a little grammar review, and then later we'll look at her homework.

There are two main uses for the word "both":

- One: **a marker of coordination** -- This is usually taught in a formal lesson. The word "both" is used to mark the first coordinate of an *and*-coordination of two coordinates. E.g. *"He likes **both** apples and pears"*, *"He likes to **both** run track and swim relays"*. This type of use is rather straightforward, and it is a basic topic taught in schools.
- Two: **a quantificational adjunct** -- This might only be lightly taught in a formal lesson, or maybe perhaps not taught at all. The word "both" is functioning as an adjunct, which is a modifier that is optional for a given sentence. It could be omitted with no loss, or almost no loss, in meaning (usually). It behaves in a similar fashion as traditional grammar's "adverbials" (which are also **adjuncts**), e.g. *"They would **both/quickly** run to school in the mornings"*.

  - It is usually possible for a speaker to place a quantificational adjunct right after the subject. (e.g. *"We **both** can sing tonight"*.)
  - When a clause is headed by an auxiliary verb, then a speaker can usually place an adjunct right after that verb; and often there could be a preference to have the adjunct located after an auxiliary. (e.g. *"They would **both/quickly** run to school in the mornings"*.)
  - When a clause is headed by a transitive lexical verb, then there will often be some resistance to having an adjunct located between the verb and its object. (e.g. * *"They play **both** the guitar"*, which is ungrammatical.)

**Auxiliary verb:** An auxiliary verb can usually be identified by verifying that it can participate in **subject-auxiliary (verb) inversion**. For example:

- *"They **are** tall"* has the subject-aux inversion of *"**Are** they tall?"*
- *"They **can** run fast"* has the subject-aux inversion of *"**Can** they run fast?"*

For those above examples, the auxiliary verbs are "are" and "can". The auxiliary verbs switched spots with the subjects when they underwent inversion.

Sometimes it might be unclear as to whether the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct or as a marker of coordination. Consider this possible ambiguous example:

- *"We can **both** sing and dance."*

The two different interpretations can be seen when it is compared against:

- *"She can **both sing and dance**."* -- [marker of coordination]
- *"**We** can **both** sing."* -- [quantificational adjunct]

---

Now let's evaluate the example choices by question.

**Question #1:**

- 1.a *They are **both** tall.*
- 1.b *They **both** are tall.*

The above two examples are grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as quantificational adjunct in both.

That is: in #1.a, the word "both" is after the auxiliary verb "are", and in #1.b, the word "both" is after the subject. And both locations are valid slots for the quantificational adjunct "both".

**Question #2:**

- 2.a *They have **both** got brown eyes.*
- 2.b *They **both** have got brown eyes.*

The above two examples are grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as quantificational adjunct in both.

That is: ditto as given for question #1 above, except that the auxiliary verb here is the verb "have".

**Question #3:**

- 3.a *They **both** like rock music.*
- 3.b *They like **both** rock music.* <-- [ungrammatical]

Example #3.a is grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct. The reason is the same as given for example #1.b above: that is, the word "both" is after the subject.

Example #3.b is **ungrammatical.** The reason it is bad is because the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct, but it is located after a transitive lexical verb ("like") and before its object.

**Question #4:**

- 4.a *They play **both** the guitar.* <-- [ungrammatical]
- 4.b *They **both** play the guitar.*

Example #4.a is **ungrammatical.** The reason it is bad is because the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct, but it is located after a transitive lexical verb ("play") and before its object.

Example #4.b is grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct. The reason is the same as given for example #1.b above: that is, the word "both" is after the subject.

**Question #5:**

- 5.a *They **both** are good at tennis.*
- 5.b *They are **both** good at tennis.*

The above two examples are grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as quantificational adjunct in both.

That is: ditto as given for question #1 above.

**Question #6:**

- 6.a *They are both lively and confident.*
- 6.b *They both are lively and confident.*

The above two examples are grammatical, but the first of the pair is ambiguous as to how it could be interpreted.

Example #6.a is grammatical because of one of the following reasons:

- The word "both" could considered to be functioning as a quantificational adjunct that is located after the auxiliary verb "are". Which is the same reason as given for example #1.a above.
- Or the word "both" could be considered to be a marker of coordination, where the two coordinates are "lively" and "confident".

Example #6.b is grammatical because the word "both" is functioning as a quantificational adjunct. The reason is the same as given for example #1.b above: that is, the word "both" is after the subject.

---

**EXTRA INFO:** Some related grammar excerpts

---

The 2002 *CGEL*, page 1305:

> **2.3** ***Both*** and ***either***
>
> The determinatives *both* and *either* function in the structure of NPs or of coordinations:
>
> [38]
>
> - i.a. *both players* - - - - b. *both Kim and Pat*
> - ii.a. *either player* - - - - b. *either Kim or Pat*
>
> In the NPs [i.a / ii.a ] they function as determiner, as described in Ch. 5, &&7.3, 7.7. In the coordinations [i.b / ii.b ] they function as marker of the first coordinate in correlative coordination: *both* is paired with *and*, while *either* is paired with *or*. (fn 25)

---

The 2002 *CGEL*, page 102:

> ***Quantificational adjuncts***
>
> A comparable difference in position between auxiliaries and lexical verbs is found with certain determinatives, such as *all, both, each* (…), that are semantically associated with the subject:
>
> [36] - - - - - LEXICAL VERB - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - AUXILIARY VERB
>
> - i.a. ***All** the players **took** a card.* - - - - - - - b. ***All** the players **had** taken a card.*
> - ii.a. *The players **all took** a card.* - - - - - - b. *The players **all had** taken a card.*
> - iii.a. * *The players **took all** a card.* (*) - - - b. *The players **had all** taken a card.*
>
> In the [i ] versions *all* belongs syntactically and semantically in the subject: it functions within the NP *all the players* and it quantifies over players. Such items can be positioned outside the NP, and the [ii ] versions show *all* in pre-verbal position. If the verb is an auxiliary, it can follow the verb, as in [iii.b ]. But it cannot follow a lexical verb, as is evident from the ungrammaticality of [iii.a ].

---

The 2002 *CGEL*, page 413:

> ***(c) Quantificational adjuncts***
>
> One use of fused-head partitives that merits separate mention here is that where they function as quantificational adjunct in clause structure:
>
> [13]
>
> - i. *Her parents **both** felt she had been exploited.*
> - ii. *They had **none of them** intended to cause so much ill will.*
>
> The quantificational adjuncts serve to quantify the subject. Example [i ] is thus equivalent to *Both her parents felt she had been exploited* and [ii ] to *None of them had intended to cause so much ill will*. Universal *all, both,* and *each* can occur as implicit partitives, while the set of determinatives found in explicit partitives is considerably larger: these three together with existential *some, any, none,* cardinal numerals, multal *many* and *much*, paucal *few, a few,* and *several*.
>
> The implicit partitives can occur in preverbal position, as in [i ]; explicit partitives are somewhat questionable in this position, strongly preferring post-auxiliary position. Compare <sup>**?**</sup>*Her parents **both of them** felt she had been exploited* and *Her parents had **both of them** felt she had been exploited*.

---

The 2002 *CGEL*, page 428:

> [7]
>
> - i.a. *We **all/both** enjoyed it.* - - - - - - - - - - b. *We had **all/both** enjoyed it.*
> - ii.a. *You **each** qualify for a prize.* - - - - - - - b. *You will **each** qualify for a prize.*
> - iii.a. *They **all five of them** complained.* - - - b. *They are **all five of them** complaining.*
>
> In this construction the underlined expressions (***italicized bold expressions***, F.E.) are quantificational adjuncts functioning in clause structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary they preferentially follow rather than precede it, as in the [b ] examples.

---

Some related examples from the 1998 *SPE*. An example is grammatical if it is unmarked (most of the examples below are grammatical).

Page 98, #2:

- *Tom's hands both were filthy.*

Page 170, #10:

- *The children all must have fallen asleep.*
- *The children must all have fallen asleep.*
- *The children must have all fallen asleep.*

Page 244, #5:

- *The employees all may have been drinking coffee.*
- *The employees may all have been drinking coffee.*
- *The employees may have all been drinking coffee.*
- % *The employees may have been all drinking coffee.* (acceptability varies dialectally)

Page 245, #6:

- *His hands were both filthy.*

Page 521, #2:

- *The guests both drank beer.*
- * *The guests drank both beer.* (ungrammatical)

---

NOTE: The 2002 *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum (et al.), *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.*

NOTE: The 1998 *SPE* is the 1998 textbook by James D. McCawley, *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*, 2nd edition, paperback.

---

OLD NOTES:

- A related topic is quantificational adjuncts, which is discussed in the 2002 CGEL, pages 102, 413, 428.
- I did a quick look at the teacher's answers. There are a number of grammar issues in play: such as, transitive verbs (e.g. "play") have a resistance to having some kinds of adjunct (e.g. "both") between the verb and its object. Also complicating the issue is that the word "both" can be a marker of coordination, e.g. "She plays both the guitar and piano".

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to be able to top this, but there's still a few days left on the bounty! Provided no betters answers will be posted, you can be assured you'll receive the points in a few days. For now though, have my gratitude.

Comment: Excellent information. Is *have* an auxiliary in *have got*, which is a phrasal   verb usually = *have* indicating possession? In other words, is *have got* a multiword item which is a main verb instead of an aux + main verb, or might some authorities balk at "splitting" the verb? This is, by the way, a genuine wonderment, not an opinion posed as a question. And is the issue relevant?

Comment: @JimReynolds 2002 CGEL has on page 112, in the section on the idiom "HAVE got": "In both varieties, however, the perfect origin of ***have*** *got* is reflected in the fact that the ***have*** component of it is an auxiliary, absolutely incompatible with ***do*** ( \* *We don't have got enough tea*--ungrammatical)." -- They also provide the examples: *"I haven't got enough tea"* with *"Have I got enough tea?"*, and *"I haven't got to read it all"* with *"Have I got to read it all?"*. So for their speakers, the verb HAVE is an auxiliary verb.

Comment: While it's true that 10/12 choices are not outright *wrong*, it's equally true that they all are ambiguous until the complete sentence is seen, and therefore alternatives should be preferred.  That is, when encountered in this location in a sentence, the mind interprets "both" as a marker of coordination, and then when the second clause fails to arrive, has to reprocess the entire sentence as a quantifier.  This can easily be avoided by joining "both" explicitly with the subject and saying "both of them", which should be preferred.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your comment sounds like an answer. Perhaps you could put it into an answer post, and maybe also provide some vetted grammar sources to support your position. -- **EDIT:** Oh, I see that you already have an answer post. Maybe you could consider adding some excerpts from vetted grammar sources that support your position into your answer post?

Comment: Re *Have got* I was just wondering to myself offhand if some idea about not splitting (some) phrasal verbs would cause some to think *have both got* is an error. // *Are* can be an aux in *They are tall*? It's the only verb. :)

Comment: @JimReynolds Comment blocks are rather small, and lack much formatting. Perhaps consider asking your questions as their own threads? (Note that "HAVE got" is an idiom. If you want more info on that topic, perhaps open a question thread for it.)

Comment: @F.E.: Phooey on "vetted grammar sources", there's more to learning and using the English language than grammar.  I have added a cognitive science reference to my answer.

Comment: I intended my remarks as feedback responses to parts of your answer because I value the answer. Maybe (and I intend humbleness) one of my responses might somehow stimulate you to clarify or improve. Maybe not. I think I erred in styling my comments so that it appeared I was interested in asking new or tangential questions. I think you incorrectly identify "are" as an auxiliary in *They are tall.*

Comment: @JimReynolds If the examples *"Are they tall?", "Is he here?"* are grammatical and acceptable to you, then you'll notice that the verb and subject had undergone a subject-aux inversion that is common to closed interrogatives. Subject-aux inversion involves auxiliary verbs, and is one of the grammatical tests used to identify them. It is a property found with auxiliaries but not with lexical verbs. (Traditional grammar has muddled the waters with its historically inaccurate terminology, and the term "auxiliary verb" is an example of that.)

Comment: @F.E. I think, given past experience an all, it might probably be worth pointing out that quantificational adjunct and marker of co-ordination are both syntactic functions, not word categories, do you reckon? Yes, I know you've said "function as" but yanno, people can easily read that the same as "functioning as an adjective" and that kind of baloney. Oh +1, excellent post. Definitely worth the time :)

Comment: @Araucaria You make a good point! But I fear that if I directly attempt to do that, I might end up in a quagmire (something similar to auxiliary verb vs lexical verb, which I had attempted to only briefly describe but probably didn't do it successfully enough). Maybe if you have any suggestions … :) -- Aside: interestingly there's the example *"The twins both both closed the windows and locked the doors"*, and hopefully the question of its acceptability won't come up in mixed company (and hopefully no one will ask about it).

Answer (score 2):

The question didn't carry the [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english) when I replied, so be aware that this answer explains the American English style.

---

As the comments say, both alternatives are worse than "they both have".

However, in context there is a clear advantage to one of them for reasons of parallel construction.

The assignment appears to have precircled "they are both (tall)", thus the complete sentence would be

```
They are  both tall and
 ||        ||
they have both got brown eyes.
```

However, the pre-chosen phrase is also bad style<sup>1</sup>, it should be

```
(They) Both are tall and both have brown eyes.     (Good, less good if "They" is included.)
```

Contrast this with correct use of both following the verb

```
My grandmother is both old and wise.
                    ^   ^        ^
                    +---+--------+
```

In this example it modifies the predicate or object, not the subject.  And that will be the natural line of thought when hearing a sentence in which the modifier is placed after the verb.

Also correct:

```
They are both tall and brown-eyed.
           ^   ^           ^
           +---+-----------+
```

but this is usable whether "they" are two or many, because "both" isn't modifying "they".

The other choice is similar:

```
They both are tall and have brown eyes.
       ^   (-+-)         (----+----)
       |     |                |
       +-----+----------------+
```

"Both" still doesn't modify the subject.  To make this clearer, consider the awkward but grammatically correct sentence (of questionable truth)

```
All fifty of the Miss USA competitors both are tall and have brown eyes.
```

or, less awkward

```
You must both sing and dance to be considered for this acting role.
```

If you wanted it to obviously modify the subject, then

```
Both of them are tall and have brown eyes.         (Good)
  ^  /\   ^
  +--  ---+
```

At best the preselected word order is ambiguous and confusing (proof follows).

---

Thanks to F.E. for bringing the correct terminology into the discussion.  To recap the issue of ambiguity, there are three functions which "both" can potentially perform:

1. quantification adjunct applied to subject
2. marker of coordination applied to two predicates (usually with different verbs)
3. marker of coordination applied to two direct objects or predicate adjectives

All examples in the question desire "both" to be interpreted as the first case, a quantification adjunct.  But none of the offered options do so unambiguously.

If "both" is placed before the verb, it can function as either 1 or 2.

If "both" is placed after the verb, it can function as either 1 or 3.

In common usage, it shouldn't appear in either location.  This provides maximum clarity.

```
They are tall and have brown eyes.
Can you sing and dance?
My grandmother is old and wise.
```

However, this doesn't provide emphasis.  For that, including "both" can be useful.

```
Both... of them... are tall and have brown eyes.
Can you sing and also dance?
My grandmother is both old and wise.
```

In these examples, only the first leaves the meaning of the term "both" momentarily ambiguous, and its function becomes clear to the reader ("fixed") very early and actively.  In the third example, "both" is fixed as soon as it appears, because it doesn't agree with the subject.  For the second example, "both" would be unclear, even after the end of the sentence, so the emphasis on coordination has been provided in a different way.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I am not saying the constructs offered by the exercise are outright incorrect from a grammatical perspective.  But they slow down comprehension<sup>2</sup>, compared to sentences starting with the unambiguous clause "Both of them".

<sup>2</sup> For a discussion of ambiguity and its effect on comprehension time and effort, one should consult the cognitive science literature, such as [Gerry Altman "Ambiguity in sentence processing"](http://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/abstract/S1364-6613(98)01153-X) [(download with no paywall)](http://cognactive.org/3303301/Altmann%20(1998).pdf)

Language learners would do well to learn the practical aspects of clear communication in addition to the borderline cases permissible according to grammar yet unclear.

Comment: -1 *Both* is linked to *they* by the [copula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) or, surprisingly enough, ***linking** verb* 'to be'. In addition, *they have both got* (or *they've both got*) is idiomatic. The homework isn't asking about your last construction, which is not idiomatic on spoken English.

Comment: @δοῦλος: There's not a single sentence here where "both" unambiguously refers to "they".  If you want clarity, say "both of them".

Comment: But that is not how people actually use English, aka, actually *talk*.

Comment: Every one of my examples will see more actual use than the phrasing in the book, I promise.

Comment: Great. You've actually provided an example from written English that does not exemplify spoken English.

Comment: *"When placed after the verb, it modifies the predicate or object, not the subject."* <== Er, but what about ***"They are both tall"***, what is your evaluation of that example?

Comment: @F.E.: Ok, more correctly, "When placed after the verb, it is initially assumed to modify the predicate, not the subject."  When the sentence ends in a way that conflicts with that assumption, one has to backtrack and re-analyze the sentence using a different meaning for "both".  "They are both tall." is grammatically correct but cognitively dissonant, while "Both of them are tall" is clear.

Comment: What ambiguity is there in ***"They both are tall"***?

Comment: @F.E.: Consider: "Basketball team X just drafted four players.  They both are tall and shoot free-throws well."  But the natural tendency is to treat "both" appearing in that position as an adjective modifying the subject, it is my alternate example that requires backtracking.

Comment: *"They both are tall and shoot free-throws well."* <== And the two or more possible different interpretations are what?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer post to show argumentation that supports your opinions.

Comment: What? Not here, not in *"**They both** are tall and shoot free-throws well."* There's nothing unfixed there when the hearer hears *"They both"*.

Comment: @F.E.: It would have been unfixed, except that in context, I just mentioned "four players".  Without that context, the ambiguity remains unresolved even from the complete sentence.

Comment: @F.E.: At this point I suspect you have been overlooking grammatically-consistent meanings.

Comment: Oh! Well, in that case, your example doesn't make sense. *"Basketball team X just drafted **four players. They both** are tall and shoot free-throws well."* It doesn't make sense because "they" can't be both 4 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: @F.E.: Does this help?  "The dogs both bark."  "Every dog both barks and runs."  "The dogs both bark and run."  In fact "All four players both are tall and shoot free-throws well." is perfectly grammatical.  After replacing "All four players" by "They", equally so.  But obviously you're confused, which supports my point that it should be avoided because it is unclear.

Comment: Put your stuff into your answer post.

Comment: @F.E.: It is already there.  Look at the diagram for "They both are tall and have brown eyes."

Comment: @F.E. Is that an improvement?  (I've also started removing obsolete comments)

Comment: *""Both" still doesn't modify the subject."* <-- But there is at least the interpretation where "both" is quantifying the subject. You need to show evidence where there is possible another different interpretation. -- Also, consider: *"All fifty of them both are tall and have brown eyes"*, as to its grammaticality.

Comment: @F.E.: My point is made by "It can mean Y."  If you meant it to mean X, and it doesn't, that's a problem.  If you object that it can also mean X, then it's ambiguous and unclear, which is a problem.  If you replace "fifty competitors" by "fifty of them" the correctness is unchanged.  It's still awkward, because of the two many meanings of "both", the one in effect is an unusual one.  In reality, "both" should simply be omitted when there's one subject, two verbs -- the conjunction "and" is perfectly sufficient to make the meaning clear.  And when there are two subjects, use "both of them".

Comment: So, in some of your examples that we've been discussion, you've been moving the "both" that's a marker of coordination up to be next to the subject, which would have been a slot for the quantification adjunct "both". And you're claiming that it is grammatical to do that. Then consider: _"He both is tall and has brown eyes"_. Your post should be discussing this sort of stuff in its argumentation.

Comment: @F.E.: It *is* grammatical.  It's also ambiguous, because that location can contain either quantification adjunct or marker of coordination.  Note that I haven't been "moving the 'both'" there, I've used "both" with a total of three different functions: quantification adjunct applied to subject, marker of coordination applied to two predicates (usually with different verbs), marker of coordination applied to two direct objects or predicate adjectives.

Comment: Put that stuff into your answer post. Present an argumentation.

Comment: Does your grammar consider *"All fifty both are tall and have brown eyes"* to be grammatical in today's English?

Comment: Yes it is grammatical, although awkward.  Subject: (All fifty).  Compound predicate: (Are tall), (Have brown eyes) joined by (Both...and...)

Comment: Why would your grammar consider the example *"All fifty both are tall and have brown eyes"* to be awkward? -- Is there anything in that example that could be causing the reader time and effort when processing it with your grammar rules?

Comment: @F.E.: The meaning of "both" gets fixed early, because it can't possibly modify the precedent subject... but it is a less common usage so it still creates some dissonance.  Probably someone has experimental data concerning the impact of unusual usages of common words on comprehension effort.  To some degree, that helps create emphasis.  But I still would likely choose "All fifty are tall and *also* have brown eyes" to direct attention the *combination* of the features.  I suppose that "All fifty both ... and also ..." is grammatical too.

Answer (score 1):

This is, frankly, a question whose answer can only be found in the nuances of the grammatical constructs your teacher is teaching you to use.

In general though (and although you did tag with british-english, I'm going to go ahead and talk about American English), both constructions make sense to me, as a native speaker, and are for the most part, interchangeable. [Here's an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+both+have%2C+they+have+both&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20both%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20have%20both%3B%2Cc0) that compares the popularity of "they both have" and "they have both" - and it's actually an interesting trend.

FWIW, I'm also inclined to note that for the purposes of emphasis in speech, I might prefer to say "they *both* have" to emphasize that "they" refers to a specific pair of people, as opposed to "they have both..."

Comment: But note that "They have both" also occurs with the meaning "They possessed or acted on two things", and "They both have" also with the meaning of "They did two actions".  It would be very difficult to pull out only the occurrences meaning "Two actors did or possessed something".